# ImageIO read gif and write to other file

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read gif file(`java.io.File`) using  ImageIO `read()` method and save it to other file using `write()`. It's a first step I want to do towards implementation of resizing gif images to create thumbnails.

Here's part of my code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
ImageIO.write(image, "gif", otherFile);
```

It saves image to other file, but it's only one frame.

I've been looking for a solution to solve this - in one place I read `BufferedImage` can hold only one frame, but I also found examples where people read gif to object of that type etc. so I'm not sure how to make it work. Should I read gif somehow frame by frame to an array of `BufferedImage` and try to save it to one file?

Comment: Do you actually want to create *animated* thumbnails?  It's complicated. But possible (I think someone actually posted the code on SO some time ago, and I want to close this as a duplicate, but I can't find it). The ImageIO API allows you to interact with the `ImageReader` and `ImageWriters`, that allows you to read individual frames/pages/layers of images. But *frame* 2 of an animated GIF is something different than *page* 2 of a multipage TIFF. Unfortunately, the API treats them the same, so you need to figure out when to create an animation or not...

Comment: PS: I would probably start by implementing thumbnails of the first frame/page/layer, and *then* implement the GIF animation part, if that really is a requirement. YMMV...

Comment: Yes, animated thumbnails are requested by client. TBH I don't like this idea, but we have almost 150GB of jpg/png thumbnails, and some of those are served over 100 times per second, so I kinda understand why my client want to create thumbnails for gifs too. I found one thread before I posted this one with something named like `SequenceWriter`. Author published that class few years ago, but that resource isn't available anymore. Thank you for suggestions. I finished work for today, but I will try to implement something based on `ImageReader` and `ImageWriter` tomorrow and let you know

Comment: I managed to save gif thumbnails using `ImageReader` and `ImageWritter`. Still have an issue because gif only loops once, but I think I'll be able to make it work correctly. Thank you for help

Comment: It would be nice if you posted your solution as an answer (and accepted it for bonus points), to help others. 